# "tls: oversized record received with length 20527" trying to "docker run" from Win10 WSL Bash only

Tags: windows, docker, tls1.2, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

## reproduction

Latest Docker Edge (18.03.0-ce-rc1-win54 (16164)) installed on Win10.

Switched to "Linux Container" before updated to latest Docker CE Edge version (but latest "Docker for Windows" UI don't show the switch option anymore?!).

No problem to run `docker run hello-world` from Windows CMD.

But calling the same from WSL Bash (latest Win10 1709) always respond with this `tls` error message:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                        TAG                        IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
continuumio/miniconda3            latest                     29af5106b6a4        17 hours ago        443 MB
hello-world                       latest                     f2a91732366c        3 months ago        1.85 kB

$ docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Thu Nov  2 20:40:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      18.03.0-ce-rc1
 API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.9.4
 Git commit:   c160c73
 Built:        Thu Feb 22 02:42:37 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

$ echo $DOCKER_HOST
tcp://0.0.0.0:2375

$ docker run hello-world
tls: oversized record received with length 20527
```

This setting seems unrelated, but necessary to run the `docker` command at all:

> Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS

## question

I wonder why this is not a common reported problem for Windows Docker / WSL usage. Something seems to be messed up, but I've no clue where to start to look into.

For example:

1. Why does the problem only appear under WSL Bash and not Windows 
   CMD?
2. How to change `daemon.json` value for `"insecure-registries": []` as some SO related messages advice?

Any help / pointers are appreciated!

(=PA=)

Comment: This is clearly a TLS/no-TLS confusion because the server is obviously responding HTTP/... (without TLS) and the client is trying to parse this as a TLS response which involves taking bytes 3 and 4 = P slash = hex 50 2F as the length and hex 502F = decimal 20527 is indeed an invalid length. HTH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

As this freaked me out a bit, I made another Google session and found the solution down in the comments of this side:
* https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly

In a nutshell:
* The issue I've described comes from an default but outdated `docker.io` installation, instead of the latest and maintained `docker-ce` installation.

Once I've removed the old one with (the trailing `*` is intended!):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge docker*
```

and installed the latest `docker-ce` one -- according to the procedure described on the page above -- the TLS issue was gone!

Happy docking.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge docker*
```

didn't work for me since as soon as I tried to run the apt-get remove command I got the following error:

```
No process in pidfile '/var/run/docker-ssd.pid' found running; none killed.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "stop" failed.
```

So I had to manually uninstall docker by executing this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/docker.io.*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/docker.io*
sudo rm /etc/default/docker
sudo rm /etc/init.d/docker
sudo rm /etc/init/docker.conf
```

and after that I just followed the instruction here:

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly

Problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to solve the problem:

1. Remove `docker.io` (if present) and related packages from WSL (Ubuntu):

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove docker.io
   sudo apt-get remove docker*
   ```

   Note: In case of errors (*[function not implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1321)*), try to [upgrade WSL](http://wsl-guide.org/en/latest/update.html) by (it'll take a while):

   ```
   sudo -S apt-mark hold procps strace sudo
   sudo -S env RELEASE_UPGRADER_NO_SCREEN=1 do-release-upgrade
   ```
2. [Install Docker CE](https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4) in  WSL (Ubuntu):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install docker-ce
   ```
3. *Expose daemon without TLS* in your [Docker app](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) on Windows.
4. Connect to it by defining `DOCKER_HOST` variable in WSL:

   ```
   export DOCKER_HOST=:2375
   ```

---

Related:

- [Cannot attach to a container on WSL](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2199) at GitHub